# Most Efficient Way to Delete Nested Array Element

Tags: php, arrays, unset

Say I have the following:

```
Array(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [item] => first item
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [item] => second item
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 5
        [item] => third item
    )

)
```

I want to delete the item with `id` = 5. I know I can loop through the array and unset, but I'm hoping for a more direct/efficient solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you cannot make the IDs the keys of the outer array (then you could simply use `unset($arr[5]);`), looping over the array is indeed the way to dg.

```
foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
    if($value['id'] === 5) {
        unset($arr[$key]);
        break;
    }
}
```

Another option would be using [`array_filter`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) - that's less efficient though since it creates a new array:

```
$arr = array_filter($arr, function($value) {
    return $value['id'] !== 5;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you create the array with the keys set as the ID's? E.g:

```
Array(
[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [item] => first item
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [item] => second item
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [id] => 5
        [item] => third item
    )

)
```

You can then write:

```
<?php    
unset($array[5]); // Delete ID5
?>
```

Comment: I'm dealing with some older JSON and can't manipulate it, unless I could translate the array somehow...

Comment: mmm I think you're only option maybe to loop through if you can't manipulate

Answer (score 1):

For Multi level nested array

```
<?php
    function remove_array_by_key($key,$nestedArray){
        foreach($nestedArray as $k=>$v){
            if(is_array($v)){
                remove_array_by_key($key,$v);
            } elseif($k==$key){
                unset($nesterArray[$k]);
            }
        }
        return $nestedArrat;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way would be to have 2 arrays.

```
ID => Index
Index => Object (your current array)
```

Search for ID in your ID => Index helper array and the value will be the Index for your main array, then unset them both.